# No sound and only Dummy Output ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04

I have tried all of the solutions listed online and none of them worked. When I have a freshly installed instance of Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed there is no sound.M y Linux kernel version is 5.4.0-40-generic. Reloading ALSA didn't work, neither did reinstalling pulse audio and ALSA. The sound isn't muted. I tried plugging the speakers through the back and front, but that didn't make a difference. No sounds are coming through headphones either. Here is the output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Desktop)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Output from `inxi -SMA`:

```
System:
  Host: main-home-pc Kernel: 5.4.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Micro-Star product: MS-7B48 v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: Z370-A PRO (MS-7B48) v: 1.0 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2.40 
  date: 03/08/2018 
Audio:
  Device-1: Logitech Webcam C250 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic
```

*Note: The Logitech Webcam is a microphone.*

And when I try to run `alsamixer`, I got the `cannot open mixer: No such file or directory` error
And when I ran `alsamixer -c 1`, I got this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/403N1.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Apparently, I had the "HD Audio Controller" turned off in the BIOS.